# Replacing an array element with for in loop

Tags: swift

I have a simple array and would like to loop through it and replace all elements with false but am having a problem with the for in loop.  An example of what I have done is below.  I am new to Swift so any help with what the loop should look like would be sincerely appreciated.

```
struct ClubMembers {
    var name: String
    var active: Bool
}

func sampleMembers() -> [ClubMembers] {
    let member1 = ClubMembers(name: "David", active: false)
    let member2 = ClubMembers(name: "John", active: false)
    let member3 = ClubMembers(name: "Mitchell", active: true)

    return [member1, member2, member3]
}
```

Comment: There's no `for` loop in the code you posted. Please show the code that you have tried and clearly explain what issues you are having.

Comment: for _ in sampleMembers() {
    _ = false
    
}

Comment: [Edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting:

```
for _ in sampleMembers() { _ = false }
```

The `_` means that you wish to ignore the value. You don't want to ignore the value, you need it.

```
for member in sampleMembers() { member.active = false }
```

But this has a couple of issues. `member` is read-only and the array is gone as soon as this line completes.

So you need to iterate each index of the array and update each value:

```
var members = sampleMembers()
for i in members.indices {
    members[i].active = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
struct ClubMembers {
    var name: String
    var active: Bool
}

func sampleMembers() -> [ClubMembers] {
    let member1 = ClubMembers(name: "David", active: true)
    let member2 = ClubMembers(name: "John", active: true)
    let member3 = ClubMembers(name: "Mitchell", active: true)

    return [member1, member2, member3]
}

var array = sampleMembers()

for i in 0..<array.count {
    array[i].active = false
}

for i in 0..<array.count {
    print(array[i].active)
}
```